# PInvoking AddSecurityPackageA

Tags: c#, .net, security, pinvoke

I am working on a project where I need to PInvoke the `secur32!AddSecurityPackageA` function, but I am still learning the ins and outs of how to do this by hand and could use some help.

Here are a the references I am working with:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sspi/nf-sspi-addsecuritypackagea
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sspi/ns-sspi-_security_package_options

And here's a sample of my code where I am trying to define the struct and call the function:

```
[DllImport("secur32.dll", EntryPoint = "AddSecurityPackageA")]
  public static extern void AddSecurityPackageA(
  ref string pszPackageName,
  ref SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS[] Options
);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet =CharSet.Ansi)]
public class SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS
{
  public ulong Size;
  public ulong Type;
  public ulong Flags;
  public ulong SignatureSize;
  public IntPtr Signature;
}

string dll = @"c:\temp\test.dll";
SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS[] pkgOpts = new SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS();

AddSecurityPackageA(ref dll, ref pkgOpts);
```

My questions are:

1. At lines 3 and 4, is this an appropriate use of `ref` and is this generally correct according to the MSDN docs?
2. At line 14, the C++ struct on MSDN  has this as a void pointer, but while researching I found that the C# equivalent is an `IntPtr`. Is that correct or do I need to use `unsafe`?
3. In general, has anyone found any really good PInvoke tutorials outside of reading other people's code? I'm moving over from Python so it is quite a bit different and much of what I've found is either "draw a circle, draw the rest of the owl" or insanely lengthy MSDN documentation that makes a lot of assumptions.

Thank you!

Comment: C++ ulong is a 32-bit, so it should be C# uint, options is just one item, not an array so it should be `ref SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS Options` if SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS is a struct, or no ref if it's a class. IntPtr is correct, you don't need unsafe (you almost never need it, it's more used for perf reasons). The function returns a 32-bit (to check for errors)

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

1. Use the `W` function rather than the `A` function. You don't want to limit yourself to ANSI. This is a Unicode world.
2. The function has a return value. You must declare the function with a matching return value type. Presumably it is `uint` or `int` but you should check in the C++ header file.
3. `ref string` is wrong. It should be `string`.
4. `ref SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS[]` is wrong. It is not an array. It is a pointer to a `struct`. Since you declared `SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS` as a class, a reference type, you can replace `ref SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS[]` with `SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS`.
5. C++ `unsigned long` is 32 bits, so it should be `uint` in C#.
6. `IntPtr` is correct, but that leaves unresolved the question of how to declare the digital signature and obtain a pointer to it. I think it's outside the remit of this question for us to track down an example of how to do that.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to you. That was immensely helpful. I have a few more questions if you don't mind.

Comment: First, I checked the `sspi.h` header file and found that the `SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS` option is marked as optional. Because of that, could I delete the struct altogether and null it out? Second, I couldn't find the output types in the header, but I did find [this](https://apidock.com/ruby/Win32/SSPI/SSPIResult) which shows that if it succeeds, it returns 0x00000000. Could I just say `if output != 0, cw(something went wrong)`?

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
    [DllImport("secur32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint AddSecurityPackage(
        string pszPackageName,
        SECURITY_PACKAGE_OPTIONS Options
    );

    [DllImport("secur32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint DeleteSecurityPackage(
        string pszPackageName
    );
```